# Print getTelephone variable in Magento

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I have a function that is calling

```
 $billing->getTelephone()
```

But it is coming up empty.  I want to echo the function to see if the data from billing is being passed properly.  But I cant print/echo it.
I tried

```
echo $billing->getTelephone();
```

&

```
  <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getShipAddress()->getTelephone()) ?>
```

On the billing page, but got fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getTelephone() on a non-object
```

How do I see the contents?

Answer (score 0):

try printing instead of echoing i.e

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($billing);
die();
```

and

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($this->getShipAddress());
die();
```

then you can try to find your variable in the array

Comment: with the die(); the page doesnt load past there, and while there is no error, there is no info?

Comment: hmm on what page are you trying to print this ?

Comment: Its onepage checkout, its on review.phtml but it should populate after hitting the finalise button as its code is onclick="billing.save(); shipping.save(); checkout.save();

Comment: i mean to ask where are you trying to use print_r() in review .phtml or the controller ? as you won't be able to print this in review.phtml

Comment: yeah im using .phtml.  Not sure what the controller is.  Ive been doing some testing and it seems everything is comes up in backend ex the telephone.  If I refresh the checkout page all fields stay filled except the telephone filed.  I checked the code and it looks the same as the others.  No idea.

Comment: check in the following folder ROOT\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Review.php

Comment: put the print_r($billing); in that file?

Comment: jon, i have checked printing your parameter on my local installation, but i dont think that this object is accessible on review.phtml file. i think there must be some another issue or i am not understanding your requirement correctly.

Comment: basically I am using a variant of IWD oncepagecart, and was trying to match it to a payment module, but it was not passing any data.  I added billing.save(); shipping.save(); to the checkout button which passed everything ex the telephone number. I am trying to find the problem with the telephone number, but I dont think it is working at all. It does not pass into the backend either.  I thought if I could see what data was being received I could work out the problem. I cant.  I think Ill just use a different variable for phone number

Comment: may be as i do not came across IWD onepagecart yet, sorry